# What's the best way to update TextMate bundles?

Tags: macos, textmate, bundle, textmatebundles

I've just realized, that some of my TextMate bundles would probably profit from updating.

The problem is, that some of them are pre-packaged with TextMate under `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles` and others are manually installed by me under `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles`.

Now the question is, if I for example wanted to update the Ruby on Rails bundle, which is under `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Ruby on Rails.tmbundle`, should I just delete it, and manually download from github into the `~/Library` folder?

**Won't I break something if I delete preinstalled bundles and replace them with newest version from GitHub?**

And second question, is there any simple way to tell TextMate to just *load all of the newest versions of installed bundles*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using GetBundles, you can get it from the bundle SVN [as described here](http://al3x.net/2008/12/03/how-i-use-textmate.html) - it's kind of a "package manager" for TM bundles, and will handle updating the builtin ones correctly too. (I also recommend the other two plugins from that blog post, but that's unrelated.)

Comment: Yes. GetBundles is THE way to go. Also don't user-installed bundles take precedence over default ones?

Comment: I believe that's how GetBundles updates "builtin" bundles - installing a separate copy of the new version into ~/Library